# Modify yaml file in bash without any external dependency

Tags: text-processing, yaml

I've multiple configurations in YAML file and I need to change some paramaters using a Bash script. Is it possible? I want to avoid using any external dependency.

My YAML Looks like

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: mic
components:
- name: Mic
  parameters:
    period_count: 4
    alsa_device_name: "pulse"

---
name: speaker
components:
- name: Speaker
  parameters:
    period_duration_ms: 20
    period_count: 4
    alsa_device_name: "pulse"
```

I want it to behave like if I provide `--mic logitec --speaker hk34` then it should modify `alsa_device_name` for both `mic` and `speaker` in my config to

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: mic
components:
- name: Mic
  parameters:
    period_count: 4
    alsa_device_name: "logitec"

---
name: speaker
components:
- name: Speaker
  parameters:
    period_duration_ms: 20
    period_count: 4
    alsa_device_name: "hk34"
```

Is it possible to do it using only Bash, and if so, how? For now I am using a Python script but this adds an extra dependency of having `python3`, which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Sure, try `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Which system are you on GNU based? or BSD? And parsing with standard text processing tools is a bad idea. Also your header line `%YAML 1.2` makes your input incompatible to YAML grammar

Comment: @Inian I'm using GNU based system.

Comment: @steve I was thinking of using sed but I'm not sure how to establish a relationship between `mic` and `alsa_device_name`. Can you give me some hint

Comment: So you don't need this to be done in bash? `sed` is OK? Can we use any other standard utilities like `perl` or `awk` all of which will be installed on a Linux system?

Comment: @terdon ya any thing which does not require external dependency should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, parsing a language like YAML that has a well defined grammar using line oriented tools is a bad idea. Don't use it in production! Never.

There are syntax aware tools for parsing YAML via command line like [Python `yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and [Go `yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). They support constructs within YAML like anchors, block literals which is not understood by standard  line oriented tools.

For one time processing like above, you could use `awk` like

```c
BEGIN {
    map["name: mic"] = "\"logitec\""
    map["name: speaker"] = "\"hk34\""
}

match($0, "name: mic") || match($0, "name: speaker") {
    key = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}

/alsa_device_name/ {
    sub(/:.*/, ": " map[key])
}

{ print }
```

You could put the above in a `awk` script (`.awk`) and run it as `awk -f script.awk yaml` or run it as part of command line. You can also define the values in the command line as

```bsh
awk -v mic='"logitec"' -v speaker='"hk34"' -f script.awk yaml
```

and process the arguments in the `BEGIN` block as

```c
BEGIN {
    map["name: mic"] = mic
    map["name: speaker"] = speaker
}
```

---

Also note that your input isn't a valid YAML file, the header line `%YAML 1.2` would make most standard YAML parsers throw an error on the syntax of your input.

Answer (score 4):

I was waiting until you accepted another answer to write this, as it adds a dependency on `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

unset mic
unset speaker

while getopts m:s: opt; do
        case $opt in
                m)
                        mic=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                s)
                        speaker=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo 'invalid option' >&2
                        exit 1
        esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

yaml_update () {
        key=${1,,}    # lower-case, e.g. "mic"
        Key=${key^?}  # title-case, e.g. "Mic"
        value=$2

        yq -Y --arg key "$key" --arg Key "$Key" --arg value "$value" '
                (select(.name == $key).components[] |
                select(.name == $Key).parameters.alsa_device_name) |= $value'
}

if [ "${mic+set}" = "set" ]; then
        yaml_update mic "$mic"
else
        cat -
fi |
if [ "${speaker+set}" = "set" ]; then
        yaml_update speaker "$speaker"
else
        cat -
fi
```

Most of the code in the script is command line parsing and logic related to the given command line options.  This was due to a requirement, or at least a suggestion, in the question to be able to use the solution with a set of convenient options on the command line.  The actual code that *does something* is in the `yaml_update` function and consists of three lines of code (the `yq` command, and it's only three lines because it would be too long on a single line).

This script would be used like so:

```bsh
./script -m logitec -s hk34 <file.yaml >file-new.yaml
```

It takes two optional command line options, `-m` and `-s` (long options, suggested in the question, are not standard and not supported by the `getopts` built-in in `bash`) to set the *mic* and/or the *speaker* Alsa device name respectively.

The YAML document is read on standard input and the resulting document is written to standard output.

The update is done with `yq` using an expression that selects the correct top-level object based on the `name` key, and then the correct array element from the `components` array using *its* `name` key.  It then updates the `alsa_device_name` value under the selected elements' `parameters` key.

For convenience, the `yq` call was moved into a shell function (we're potentially doing two extremely similar calls to `yq`, so this seemed reasonable).

The output, if changing the given document like shown above, would be

```yaml
name: mic
components:
  - name: Mic
    parameters:
      period_count: 4
      alsa_device_name: "logitec"
---
name: speaker
components:
  - name: Speaker
    parameters:
      period_duration_ms: 20
      period_count: 4
      alsa_device_name: "hk34"
```