# Generate full paths from nested (for example yaml) directory structure

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I try to write script in shell/bash that will convert yaml directory structure to full paths (for further `mkdir -p` it). Yaml is my choice because of human-editability. Structure example is:

```yaml
- Downloads
    - Music
    - Movies
- University
    - First year
        - English
        - Maths
    - Second year
```

So I want to replace first-level with current dir (`realpath .`), for example, `/home/maeda/Downloads`, second with parent dir's full path (for example, `/home/maeda/Downloads/Music`)

So I want to achieve this result:

```
/home/maeda/Downloads
/home/maeda/Downloads/Music
/home/maeda/Downloads/Movies
/home/maeda/University
/home/maeda/University/First year
/home/maeda/University/First year/English
/home/maeda/University/First year/Maths
/home/maeda/University/Second year
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify yaml file in bash without any external dependency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662607/modify-yaml-file-in-bash-without-any-external-dependency)

Comment: Your input does not appear to be valid YAML.  Please consider updating your question.  Can we assume that all the entries designate _directories_?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your YAML file is valid, such as

```yaml
Downloads:
    Music:
    Movies:
University:
    First year:
        English:
        Maths:
    Second year:
```

you may use

```bsh
yq -r --arg prefix "$(realpath .)" 'paths | [ $prefix, .[] ] | join("/")' file.yaml
```

where `yq` is from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

This uses a `jq` expression to get the "paths" from the document.  A "path" in this context is a representation of any specific entry in the document itself, so the path of the `First year` array is the array `[ 'University', 'First year' ]` (written using JSON notation).

These path arrays may be joined with `/` as the delimiter using `join("/")`.

I'm also passing the output of `realpath .` into `yq` as the value of the internal variable `$prefix`.  This value is added to the front of each of the path arrays before passing them through `join("/")`, which means that it will be prepended to the pathnames outputted by the `yq` command.